# Extension of family of operators

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A(z)$ where $z\in \mathbb{R}$ be a family of (bounded) operators on some Hilbert space. Assume we know these operators have a meromorphic extension to all of $\mathbb{C}$. Assume moreover that we happen to know that they satisfy the condition 
$$
A(z)^\ast = A(z)^{-1} 
$$ 
for $z\in \mathbb{R}$. How does this imply that the extension satisfies 
$$
A(\overline{z})^\ast = A(z)^{-1}
$$
for $z\in \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first condition can be also written as 
$$A(\bar z)^\ast = A(z)^{-1},\quad z\in\mathbb R\tag1$$
Now both sides of (1) are meromorphic functions of $z\in\mathbb C$. They agree on a set with a limit point (namely the real line), and therefore agree identically.

If you don't take for granted that the [Identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) holds for operator-valued functions, then apply it to $\varphi(A(\bar z)^\ast - A(z)^{-1})$ where $\varphi:B(\mathcal H)\to\mathbb C$ is any linear functional.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the "identity theorem" is for functions which agree on a  nonempty open set. In this case, it would be closer to something like the "isolated zero principle".

Comment: @julien The Wikipedia article to which I linked gives both versions. I think it's mostly a matter of choice for textbook authors.

Comment: The "identity principle" doesn't require a non-empty open, merely _any_ set with an accumulation point.

Comment: @paulgarrett Of course, if it is true with an accumulation point, it is true with an open set. I've seen both names, depending on the assumption. Not a big deal, of course.

Comment: Thank you 40 votes for your reply. I suppose what I'm wondering is why $A(z)^\ast $ is not meromorphic, but only $A(\overline{z})^\ast $?

Comment: @jiku1797 Consider a power series for $A$. It has terms like $z^nA_n$. Taking adjoint gives $\bar z^n A_n^*$ which is anti-holomorphic. In other words, it's a holomorphic function of $\bar z$.

Comment: @40 votes Of course, thank you so much.